# Mathematica gives wrong answer for a definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I tried to compute the definite integral

```
Integrate[Exp[Pi I  t]/((-I + 1 + t) Cosh[Pi t]), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

and obtained the answer (version 11.2.0.0)

```
(2 t^((1 - I) \[Pi]) ((-1 + I) + t^(2 I \[Pi]) ((-1 + I) + Log[t]) 
- Log[t]))/((1 + t^(2 \[Pi])) (2 I + Log[t]^2))
```

This expression depends on t the integration variable. I plotted the real part 
and it is not constant.

I am interested in the integral.

Comment: This has to be a bug. How could definite integration return expression with `t` in it? Version 11.1.1 (one before 11.2) does not even solve this. screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DL7DJ.png)  so something changed in 11.2 integrate to cause this.

Comment: @Nasser Yes your screen shot is what I expected as an answer when I tried the integral. I suspected a possible bug, but the answer was so surprising that I asked, perhaps my input has something wrong.

Comment: Why not use `NIntegrate`? I confirm your errors in macOS 10.13 y MMA 11.2, when using `Integrate`.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas  I am interested in a closed form, not exactly of this but a slightly more complicated integral. After the error I simplified a little the integrand. I know NIntegrate will usually compute in other way.

Comment: Eeeeeeek (extra letters more for the comment min size limitation than effect..)

Comment: Doesn’t @DanielLichtblau saying Eeeeeek count as being vetted by the community as a bug?

Comment: @march I wrote that after editing to add the "bugs' tag. It's not there now, so either I did not correctly update or else it got removed later. I'll put it in again.